# How to use asm/system.h from user space?

Tags: c, network-programming, linux-kernel

For my Linux networking application, I am referring to [lincap.c](http://www.scaramanga.co.uk/code-fu/lincap.c) to understand how to use the PACKET_MMAP method of receiving Ethernet packets via a ring buffer.

lincap.c uses the memory barrier macro `mb()` defined in asm/system.h. However, the code in that header file is embraced by `#ifdef __KERNEL__`. I guess that means it is a kernel header file.  How can I use `mb()` from a user space application (which I believe lincap.c is)?

BR

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the [`__sync_synchronize`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fsync_005fsynchronize-2810) builtin gcc provides. I'm not sure whether it generates exactly the same code, but it should be similar enough in effect. So simply defining `mb` as an alias to that should work.